# Accessing files copied to output from a docker container

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, .net-5

I'm trying to create a sharedsettings.json file that will be copied to all docker containers in a microservice based solution.

I've created a link in each project to the file and set it to copy to output directory. Each .csproj file contains

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\sharedsettings.json" Link="sharedsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

When I try to access the file from my code though, I can't find the file.
I have the following in my Program.cs

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder<TStartup>(string[] args) where TStartup : class
{
    return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
               .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
               {
                   var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;

                   config
                       .AddJsonFile("sharedsettings.json", optional: false)
                       .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
                       .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

                    config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
               })
}
```

The app aborts on startup with the error "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The configuration file 'sharedsettings.json' was not found and is not optional. The physical path is '/app/sharedsettings.json'"

When I insert a breakpoint and use the immediate window in Visual Studio to try and explore the files available I get the following

```
Directory.GetFiles(env.ContentRootPath)
{string[6]}
    [0]: "/app/appsettings.Development.json"
    [1]: "/app/appsettings.json"
    [2]: "/app/Bluesheets.csproj"
    [3]: "/app/Dockerfile"
    [4]: "/app/Program.cs"
    [5]: "/app/Startup.cs"

Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath), "..")
{string[0]}
```

Where are the rest of my files and how do I access the sharedsettings.json?

I'm currently running using docker-compose in Visual Studio
My docker files are just the default Visual Studio generated ones, e.g.

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Clients/Clients.csproj", "Clients/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Clients/Clients.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Clients"
RUN dotnet build "Clients.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Clients.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Clients.dll"]
```

Answer (score 0):

after you have created your container,

1. Access the file system on the container and check if the files were copied successfully, if not check from the source to the location the files will be copied to.
2. The permissions needs to be checked and may need amending.

Comment: I'm still quite new to Docker but when I open a cli prompt from within docker desktop, it seems that within the app folder, I did find sharedsettings.json but it was at app/bin/Debug/net5.0/appsettings.json
I'm assuming there must be a better way to access the file as the path will clearly change when I use release mode or even upgrade to .Net6 in the future.

Comment: You could have a shared folder for multiple dockerfiles to use, so when you are building a docker image the dockerfile will copy the file you want copied.